# mediaelement.js play youtube source on android phone chrome

Tags: android, youtube-api, mediaelement.js

The problem is using mediaelement.js to play "youtube source" on android phone chrome.
For example, I use the android phone's chrome(33.0.1750.136) open [YouTube API Example](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube) and tap the left small playing button. The video doesn't load and duration is zero, but tap the big center playing button the video is fine.

In other case, when I use mediaelement.js and set code like `mediaElement.play();` will get the same problem.

I want to find a method to control playing "youtube source" on android phone chrome by mediaelement.js.